# Facebook Graph API | Search Unique Page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook Graph API to search a unique Facebook Page. I am using below API URL for the same:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={query}&type=page&access_token={access_token}
```

The result of the above API is a JSON array with the matched Facebook Page objects which has Page Id, Page Name and Category.

But my need is to find out the unique Facebook Page using URL path name. For example, if I enter 'nike'(taken from below address), I should get the Facebook page id of the Nike's page.

```
https://www.facebook.com/nike/
```

Is there any way to get achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use search, just make a simple API request using the page name:

`/nike`

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=nike&version=v2.8